# SVG polyline gradient apply only to stroke

Tags: html, css, svg, polyline

I'm new in svg drawing.

Is there any option to colorize an svg `<polyline>` with gradient? I need to colorize only stroke, but all filters I founded is applied gradient both to stroke and body.

In fact I'm trying to make glow neon effect like this: http://screencloud.net/v/j2hE and it works fine for now with code below when I'm draw a strict line:

```
<linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffd95d"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffd95d" stop-opacity="0" />
</linearGradient>
```

But when I'm drawing a line by circle, it looks like:
http://screencloud.net/v/9M6x (bottom is start and around circle to top where finish). As you can see, gradiend is applied to all polyform, but I need it to be gradiented only line as I draw it.

Is there any option to make neon glow lines like I need it?
For better understanding - I'm trying to get effect similar to default Windows screensaver named "glowing lines".

Comment: What does the markup of the object you're drawing the gradient on look like? What would the object look like if it was drawn the way you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750227/svg-gradient-as-polylines-stroke-background-with-absolute-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to apply a linearGradient along the length of a line's stroke.

The only way you could do it is to draw a sequence of individually coloured line/path segments that slowly fade out.